# Set imagesource of wpf image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagesource

I know that there are a few similiar questions but they don´t help me:

Have got the following code to show a Image in code behind:

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new `Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;component/Images/Klar.JPG");`
logo.EndInit();
```

The image is in the Images folder at the same level as the `bin` folder.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Ensure that the BuildAction is `Content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information about Pack URIs see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). I believe yours should be:

```
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Klar.JPG");
logo.EndInit();
```

which assumes that at the project level you have a folder called Images which contains a jpg called Klar.JPG.